# Amazon S3 as file-storage

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, openshift

Openshift has restrictions in storage-size at about 1GB to 6GB.

If you are hosting user-generated content thats not that much.

Using S3 as NAS might be a solution. What I would like to do, is to let my webapp upload to S3 and download the currently needed stuff from S3 to my app... That way my guests would not directly access the S3-stored files and I might be able to reduce the S3-traffic. Speed is not that critical.

Is that a common approach? May it be against their TOS?

Comment: Also additional gear storage (up to 30GB) is available starting from the Bronze plan: https://developers.openshift.com/en/managing-resource-management.html#additional-gear-storage

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to https://www.openshift.com/content/amazon-s3-mounted-locally#comment-25664, it is not against their TOS.  In fact, it was a Red Hat employee who posted the response.  Based on the number of OpenShift requests related to S3, I would say it is fairly common.

Comment: But if I understand him correctly, he is arguing for the exact opposit: "Direct your user directly to S3". Isn't he?

Comment: I don't think so.  The specific question he was answering was whether or not to mount S3 buckets under the OpenShift file system.  His contention, I think, was that the application would manage the interaction with S3 rather than the OpenShift instance.  I did not take it to mean that the user would interact with S3 directly.

Answer (score 1):

I can't seem to find anything in our TOS that indicates this as a violation. However, what Corey was pointing out is that there is likely a better way to go about it then mounting it locally. Perhaps you can provide a few more details about your app and we can point you in the right direction.

Comment: It is just another social website (because the world can't have enough of them ;)) and I would like to use S3 for avatars. I'm using cake and so caching the S3-stored images wouldn't be hard. Thanks for your answer